# Is valid value angular 7 form field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular7

I have created a function which checks if input value is valid or not.

The function:

```
error_message = '';

constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    title: [
      '',
      [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8),
        Validators.maxLength(24),
      ],
    ],
    person: ['', Validators.required],
    money_type: ['', Validators.required],
    price: ['', Validators.required],
  });
  this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
  });
}

isValidPrice() {
  if (!this.firstFormGroup.get('price').value) {
    this.price_error = 'You must set a price';
    return false;
  } else if (this.firstFormGroup.get('price').value < 1000) {
    this.price_error = 'Minimum price is 1000';
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

And the HTML code:

```
        <mat-form-field
          hintLabel="Set a price"
          class="information-form-field"
        >
          <input
            matInput
            placeholder="Price"
            formControlName="price"
            type="number"
            required
            max="9999999999"
            min="1000"
            #title
          />
          <mat-error *ngIf="!isValidPrice()">{{ price_error }}</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

But there is a problem, whether I input any value, the function works and the error displays, but when I input a value less than 1000, the function doesn't work and I cannot understand why. Could you, please, help me to determine the problem and help to get a solution, or if you have more suitable decisions for this situation. Give some advises. Thank you!

Comment: possibly because your price is a string and not a number

Comment: can you create the stackblitz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to state the minimum validator on your component by using `Validators.min()`. Also, it may be better to pass an initial value of null to your form controls. You may refer to the code below

component.ts

```
this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    title: [
      null,
      [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8),
        Validators.maxLength(24),
      ],
    ],
    person: [null, Validators.required],
    money_type: [null, Validators.required],
    price: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1000)]],
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use min validator to validate price, not to create whole function, use `Validators.min(1000)` and `Validators.max(99999...)` , to check for error just use 
`<mat-error *ngIf="firstFormGroup.controls[price].valid">{{ price_error }}</mat-error>`

Comment: create stackblitz please